# Writing a parameterless function in Ramda in a point free style?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Consider the working code below:

```
var randN = x => () => Math.floor(x*Math.random());
var rand10 = randN(10)
times(rand10, 10) // => [6, 3, 7, 0, 9, 1, 7, 2, 6, 0]
```

`randN` is a function that takes a number and returns an RNG that, when called, will return a random int in the range [0, N-1].  So it's a factory for specific RNGs.

I've been using [ramda.js](http://ramdajs.com/), and learning functional programming theory, and my question is: Is it possible to rewrite `randN` in a point free style using ramda?

For example, I could write:

```
var badAttempt = pipe(multiply(Math.random()), Math.floor)
```

This would satisfy the "point-free style" requirement, but fails to behave the same way as `randN`: calling `badAttempt(10)` simply returns a single random number between 1 and 10, rather than a *function* that generates a random number between 1 and 10 when called.

I have not been able to find a combination of ramda functions that enables me to do the rewrite in a point-free style.  I can't tell if this is just a failure on my part, or something special about using `random`, which breaks referential transparency and therefore may be incompatible with a point free style.

### update

my own slight variation on the solution, after discussing it with Denys:

```
randN = pipe(always, of, append(Math.random), useWith(pipe(multiply, Math.floor)), partial(__,[1,1]))
```

Comment: The `randN` in your first line of code is infinitely better than the Rambda implementation in your last line. Chasing point-free style at the cost of readability is a huge mistake.

Comment: clearly.  i never claimed it was better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var randN = R.converge(R.partial, [R.wrap(R.pipe(R.converge(R.multiply, [Math.random, R.identity]), Math.floor), R.identity), R.of])
var rand10 = randN(10)
alert(R.times(rand10, 10)) // => [3, 1, 7, 5, 7, 5, 8, 4, 7, 2]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.19.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This would help with an extra function for abstracting a function to re-evaluate its arguments each time it is called.

```
thunk = fn => R.curryN(fn.length, (...args) => () => fn(...args))
```

The only purpose of this function would be to cause some side effect within the given `fn` function.

Once we have `thunk` function, we can define `randN` like so:

```
randN = thunk(R.pipe(S.S(R.multiply, Math.random), Math.floor))

R.times(randN(10), 5) // e.g. [1, 6, 9, 4, 5]
```

Note: `S.S` here is the [S combinator from Sanctuary](http://sanctuary.js.org/#S) which does effectively the same thing as `R.converge(multiply, [Math.random, identity])`.

I do however only recommend going with a point-free solution if it actually improves the readability of a function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  And yes, this was merely an exercise.  My original point-full solution is obviously much better than any of the point-free suggestions, in this case.

Comment: `thunk` does have one more advantage in an eagerly evaluated language: it allows one to configure,  but delay performing, some expensive computation until it's certain the result is needed.  This, more than the side effects, might be a good argument for including it in Ramda.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's a good idea to learn functional programming using a specific library, because the characteristics of a lib and the functional paradigm will mix inevitably. In practice, however, Ramda is incredibly useful. It bridges the gap between the imperative reality and the functional [Fantasy Land](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land) in Javascript :D

Here's a manual approach:

```
// a few generic, reusable functions:
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x)); // mathematical function composition
const comp2 = comp(comp)(comp); // composes binary functions
const flip = f => x => y => f(y)(x); // flips arguments
const mul = y => x => x * y; // first class operator function

// the actual point-free function:
const randN = comp2(Math.floor)(flip(comp(mul)(Math.random)));

let rand10 = randN(10); // RNG
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(rand10());
```

It's worth mentioning that `randN` is impure, since random numbers are impure by definition.

Comment: Thanks, I think your manual approach is instructive.  Could you elaborate on your last 2 sentences?  I'm missing the connection you see between this problem and monads.  And while I get that using `Math.random` makes it impure, I didn't understand why composing a nullary function would make it impure.

Comment: I know what Monads are, the question was just about the relation to this problem.  I guess your suggestion to contain the effect of random within a monad?

Comment: @Jonah I've withdrawn the last paragraph of my reply. IO monads and impurity are different notions. Both seem to have an intersection when it comes to IO-related side effects, that's all. Sorry for the confusion!